# Color space to Camera space transformation matrix

Tags: camera-calibration, kinect-v2

I am looking for transformation matrix to convert [color space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorspacepoint.aspx) to [camera space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx).

I know that the point conversion can be done using [CoordinateMapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.coordinatemapper.aspx) but I am not using Kinect v2 official APIs.

I really appreciate if someone can share the transformation matrix, which can convert color space to camera space.

As always, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important : The raw kinect RGB image has a distortion. Remove it first.**

**Short answer**

The "transformation matrix" you are searching is called projection matrix.

[image]

```
rgb.cx:959.5
rgb.cy:539.5
rgb.fx:1081.37
rgb.fy:1081.37
```

**Long answer**

First understand how color image is generated in Kinect.

[image]

*X, Y, Z* : coordinates of the given point in a coordinate space where kinect sensor is consider as the origin. AKA camera space. Note that camera space is 3D.

*u, v* : Coordinates of the corresponding color pixel in color space. Note that color space is 2D.

*fx , fy* : Focal length

*cx, cy* : principal points (you can consider the principal points of the kinect RGB camera as the center of image)

*(R|t)* : Extrinsic camera matrix. In kinect this one you can consider as *(I|0)* where *I* is identity matrix.

*s* : scaler value. you can set it to 1.

To get the most accurate values for the *fx , fy, cx, cy*, you need to calibrate your rgb camera in kinect using a chess board.

The above *fx , fy, cx, cy* values are my own calibration of my kinect. These values are differ from one kinect to another in very small margin.

**More info and implementaion**

[All Kinect camera matrix](https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction/tree/master/calibration)

[Distort](https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction/blob/db1f4ffe10059eb6af01ecc12846c3b2bd0a003f/registration.cpp#L10)

[Registration](https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction/blob/db1f4ffe10059eb6af01ecc12846c3b2bd0a003f/registrationCuda.cu#L62)

I implemented the Registration process in CUDA since CPU is not fast enough to process that much of data (1920 x 1080 x 30 matrix calculations per second) in real-time.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for delayed response. I have one more question. The [link](https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction/tree/master/calibration) contains 4 calibration files i.e., _camera_param.yaml_, _depth_calibration.yaml_, _pose_calibration.yaml_ and _rgb_calibration.yaml_. At present, I am using AR marker library in ROS, which requires [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) along with RGB image acquired from Kinect in order to calculate 3D position of AR marker.

Comment: In `sensor_msgs/CameraInfo` the distortion model is `plumb_bob`. Intrinsic camera matrix `K` consists of `fx`, `fy`, `cx` and `cy`, which you have already shared. So no worries! But how to get other parameters such as distortion parameters `D` consisting of 5 parameters are `k1`, `k2`, `t1`, `t2`, `k3` and others?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shanil. Can you explain please how to take inverse of 3x4 matrix? I just read about ["extrinsic matrices"](http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/22/extrinsic/) but I'm not sure how to deal with it programmatically (python)